# React/Redux - Why is my action/reducer not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Newbie here. Trying to get my Redux `action` to talk to my reducer and update the `store`. 
 - TL;DR question further down:

*Context*: I am only really getting issues now that i'm trying to split out my actions/reducers into separate files and folders. Prior to this i got everything working, when it was all in one file, sort of thing.

So... I have 3 files. 
 
i) A Client.js (top level, where my store is), which takes my reducer in and then uses `provider` to *get* the store to `<Main />`

Main.js then uses `mapDispatchToProps` to get a `toggleLogin` action(creator) *into* its `onClick` prop.

This is then passed down to `<LoginButton />` where `onClick` can be clicked. And when it *is*, i can get a console log from the toggleLogin action-creator. But any attempt to return { type: 'TOGGLE_LOGIN' } sees either a:

'ReferenceError: store is not defined' or no change... and i have to console.log either side to find the problem sits within that `return {}` area. So...

*TL;DR Question* why wont my reducer pick-up that action and update the store? Its driving me nutty.

ClientJS:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Redux from 'redux';

import Main from './Components/Main'

import { myReducer } from './Reducers/reducer';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


const store = createStore(myReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Main />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Main.Js

```
import React from 'react';

import LoginButton from './LoginButton';
import PlayButton from './PlayButton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { toggleLogin } from '../actions/toggleLogin';

const Main = (props) => {

const { onClick} = props;

  return (
    <div>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
      <LoginButton onClick={onClick} />
      <PlayButton />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn
  }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    onClick: toggleLogin,
  }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

reducer.js:

```
export const myReducer = (state = { isLoggedIn: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_LOGIN':
    return {
      isLoggedIn: !action.isLoggedIn
    }

    default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

LoginButton.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Redux from 'redux';

const LoginButton = (props) => {

  const { onClick } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>LOGIN/LOGOUT</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginButton;
```

toggleLogin.js (action creator):

```
export function toggleLogin() {
  console.log('this works');
  store.dispatch({
    type: 'TOGGLE_LOGIN',
  });
  console.log('this doesnt work');
}
```

Comment: `toggleLogin` should just return `{type: 'TOGGLE_LOGIN'}`. `bindActionCreators` is what wraps that function in a `store.dispatch` call, so you are basically trying to dispatch it twice, and inside your function there is no `store` reference.

Comment: It's undefined because you don't import it--but an action creator should just be returning an object, not dispatching.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton & @SergiuParaschiv - not entirely sure how i would go about importing the store into that action though? I thought the purpose of `connect()` and `<Provider store={store} /> ` was that dispatch/actions and state/store were then accessible throughout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toggleLogin` should just return `{type: 'TOGGLE_LOGIN'}`. `bindActionCreators` is what wraps that function in a `store.dispatch` call, so you are basically trying to dispatch what another dispatch returns.
Also you get that 'ReferenceError: store is not defined' exception because inside your function there is no `store` reference.

Comment: Thanks @SergiuParaschiv i did actually take the `store.dispatch({..` out of the toggleLogin.js and had it just set to: <br><br>

`export function toggleLogin() {
console.log('this does work');
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_LOGIN'
  }
  console.log('this doesnt work');
}`

And the first con-log worked but the second didnt. 

So i'm still a bit lost as to how changing it to the object with just type will fix it. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Just closing the loop on this one - looks like it was a mesh of things:
i) my `TOGGLE_LOGIN` was indeed trying to dispatch. It should've just been returning an object. 
ii) i *did* need `bindActionCreators` but it would've been more appropriate with more than one action. 
iii) most importantly - when i was changing my `TOGGLE_LOGIN` to return an object... i was putting two console logs either side of it, for debugging purposes. But being a newbie/absent minded, i totally overlooked that this was effectively putting a function after a return statement. Once i took the console-logs off, i was up and running. Thanks everyone.