# Update a redux array of object but not re-render the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

#### PROBLEM STATEMENT

I am trying to modify a array of objects that is stored in redux store. After updating from a component it doesn't re-render the component.
Basically, I take a redux-state which is a array of objects using `mapStateToProps`. Then, update a object in this array from a react component. I expect when the array is manipulated the component will re-render with updated array. But, unfortunately when I update the object of this array, my component can't detect the changes.

#### REDUX STATE

```js
const initialState = {
  basket: [
      {id: 1, name: "", quantity: 1},
      {id: 2, name: "", quantity: 1},
      {id: 3, name: "", quantity: 1},
  ],
};

// My Reducers
const foodReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   .....................
   .....................
   .....................
}
```

#### REACT COMPONENT

Here, `increaseItem` function just update the quantity of a item.
**Note :** When `increaseItem` function called, **redux-dev-tools** shows the changes.

```js
function Ordered({ basket }) {
  // INCREASE FOOD ITEM
  const increaseItem = (id) => {
    basket.map(food => {
      if(food.id === id){
        food.quantity++;
      }
    });

   useEffect(() => {
     console.log(basket);
   }, [JSON.stringify(basket)]);
   
  return (
   {basket.length > 0 &&
      basket.map((food) => (
        <div className="ofood" key={food.id}>
        <div className="no">{food.id}</div>
        <div className="name">{food.name}</div>
        <div className="quantity">
          <div className="btn" onClick={() => increaseItem(food.id)}> + </div>
          <div>{food.quantity}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
 );
}

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { 
      basket: state.food.basket,
    };
  };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Ordered);
```

How can I resolve this issue ????

Comment: Here, You need to update the basket state in the reducer using actions.

Comment: There’s in-place mutation going on and no action is being dispatch at the same time. To make it work, it should be the opposite of that: an action should be dispatched with the new value, and no mutation of the state should happen for Redux to pick up the change and trigger the component render (see [official docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data)). Check out this post as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469157/react-redux-why-is-my-action-reducer-not-working

Comment: As @saksh73 said, you need to create a reducer to update the redux state. Genrally those state update actions are exposed to your components via actions. Please check this example on the redux docs. Its pretty thorough in terms of how to achieve the above.
https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples#shopping-cart

Comment: @saksh73 Actually, the process I described above successfully updated the redux state. This is why I don't use actions.

UPDATE: I update the basket state in reducer using action also. Unfortunately It also update my basket state but not re-render like before. Do you please elaborate your answer??

Comment: @Mizanur - Could you please show how are you updating the state in your reducer.

Comment: @MizanurRahman you need to share the code of your reducer, especially the case where you update your object in array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`food.quantity++` is a mutation of the Redux state.  This will cause the value in Redux to change, but the component will not re-render because you mutated the data rather than updating it properly.

As far as React is concerned, `basket` hasn't changed since the array contains the same items as before.  You mutated one of those items such that the `quantity` is different, but React doesn't know that.  That's why you had to use `JSON.stringify(basket)` in your `useEffect` dependencies instead of `basket`.

---

You cannot call `food.quantity++` in your reducer either, unless you are using a helper library like [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started).  Every object that you change must be replaced with a copied version.  A non-mutating reducer should look like this:

```
const foodReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREASE_QUANTITY":
      return {
        ...state,
        basket: state.basket.map((food) => {
          if (food.id === action.payload) {
            return {
              ...food,
              quantity: food.quantity + 1
            };
          } else return food;
        })
      };
  }
};
```

---

With Redux Toolkit, it's a lot simpler.

```
export const foodSlice = createSlice({
  name: "food",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increaseItem(state, action) {
      state.basket.forEach((food) => {
        if (food.id === action.payload) {
          // it's ok to do this with Redux Toolkit
          food.quantity++;
        }
      });
      // don't return anything, just modify the draft state
    }
  }
});

export const {increaseItem} = foodSlice.actions;
export default foodSlice.reducer;
```

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { increaseItem } from "../store/slice";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function Ordered({ basket, increaseItem }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(basket);
  }, [JSON.stringify(basket)]);

  return (
    <div>
      {basket.map((food) => (
        <div className="ofood" key={food.id}>
          <div className="no">{food.id}</div>
          <div className="name">Food: {food.name}</div>
          <div className="quantity">
            <div className="btn" onClick={() => increaseItem(food.id)}>
              + Add One
            </div>
            <div>Current Quantity: {food.quantity}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    basket: state.food.basket
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { increaseItem })(Ordered);
```

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-update-basket-array-597bi?file=/src/components/App.tsx)